# Weird crash on samsung devices

Tags: android, exception, crash

There's this weird exception in Samsung phones specifically Galaxy S7 Edge, which we noticed in Fabric crash reports:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.someapp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.someapp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.someapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.someapp-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.someapp-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3331)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.someapp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.someapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.someapp-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.someapp-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3326)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

As a feedback from users, this error happens only when app is in the background and there's not interaction with it, I think the issue lies in the way Samsung's device rom tries to minimize background tasks or put them in a special memory and our app is not ready and this happens.

The point is the exception is not pointing to any class of the app so we can trace the issue, If anyone has encountered this problem before please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests

Comment: did you enable multidex in your app?

Comment: Yep, Its enabled but this doesnt have anything to do with multidex, at least I think so

Comment: Hi, I had a problem with classloaders using compat libs. I've "workaround" it changing the classloader before each of my json deserialization. Maybe it is somehow related and you can fix it the same way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070976/flexjson-classnotfound-exception-on-android-4-4-4

Comment: try to add  android:largeHeap="true" in manifest.

Comment: @MohammadReza please post your `build.gradle` and `Manifest` please

Comment: @eduyayo Thanks for your comment, but in no way its associated with Json deserialization, it happens in the background while app is doing nothing

Comment: @parikdhakan It's already turned on

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Nothing special in the build.gradle, a few dependencies and multidex is turned on

Comment: enable multiDex in the gradle : multiDexEnabled true

Comment: 1. Do you use ProGuard? 2. I see lib/armeabi-v7a in crash report, but Samsung Galaxy works in 64 bit mode, so it uses arm64-v8a

Comment: Is there a chance that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601373/unable-to-instantiate-receiver-java-lang-classnotfoundexception Check the accepted answer.

Comment: Are you saying "com.someapp" is the actual class returned in the error? This wasn't sanitized before posting?

Comment: @PabloBaxter Its my app's package name!, the thing is it doesnt point to any class of my app just says the package name's broadcast is not registered!

Comment: @BhalchandraSW nope! there's no unregistered broadcast receiver in my code!

Comment: Can you post the manifest?

Comment: pls, try changing the classloader. if you see the link, I've opened an issue in google devrs site telling the classloader changes and have to be restored. They call this a feature...

Answer (score 0):

try this.. its work for me where i have the same problem on different devices

add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` to your dependencies.

make sure you put `multiDexEnabled true` in defaultConfig

then add this in your Application class

```
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From `Marshmallow`, Google has introduced a new feature/mode called `Doze`. According to official documents

> Starting from Android 6.0 (API level 23), Android introduces two power-saving features that extend battery life for users by managing how apps behave when a device is not connected to a power source. Doze reduces battery consumption by deferring background CPU and network activity for apps when the device is unused for long periods of time. App Standby defers background network activity for apps with which the user has not recently interacted.

You can read it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) in detail.

In `Nougat`, it has been more optimized.

I believe the problem is actually the `Doze` feature. I don't know if there's any way to prevent this, but you can manually do it. You can refer [here](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2993199/android/how-to-turn-off-doze-mode-for-specific-apps-in-android-marshmallow.html) and [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/inside-marshmallow-what-doze-how-do-i-use-it-and-what-does-it-do) for more detail

Comment: I'm afraid this'd be the case, because this just happens on samsung phones, especially S7 Edge